# How Do I Fix This Error Without Loosing Stored Blocks On Pc?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, full-node, installation

I opened my Bitcoin Core program today on my Windows 7 PC via an external hard disk (1 TB) and I found the following *error*:

> MinGW Runtime Assertion
> Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: E:\Blockchain\bitcoin-qt.ex
> File: chain.cpp, line 103
>
> Expression: pindexWalk-> pprev

DEBUG LOG: http://pastebin.com/YNEuRAcv

How do I fix this error without losing the blocks on my external hard disk which I have synchronized for months?

Comment: "For months"? Is your Internet connection very much constrained? If not, it won't take that long. If you can allocate >6GB of RAM or simply use the blocksdir configuration to migrate the intensively accessed chainstate subdirectory to SSD if you have one.

Comment: Hello Chris Chris, my internet connection is very slow. How do I fix Bitcoin Core MinGW Runtime Assertion Assertion Failed error?